# when to use TYPE and LIKE in ABAP

Tags: abap

Why is this error

> NAME must a flat structure you can not use internal table,string referenceses or structure as component

raised when I am using type in place of like in line no 2) dosen't show any error, when I am using like shows error.

What is the difference between `LIKE` and `TYPE`?

Code:

```
TYPES name(20) type c.    
data student_name like name.   "<=============== like or type
student_name = 'satya'.   
write student_name.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have created `name` as a `type`. Therefore, if you declare a variable of **type** `name`, you need to write the statement as `data student_name type name.`.

Now if you want to create another variable **like** the variable `student_name`, you would use the `like` keyword in the declaration as `data student_name2 like student_name.`

For a more detailed explanation, refer to the [documentation](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70/helpdata/en/fc/eb2ff3358411d1829f0000e829fbfe/content.htm)